# Can I open Google Sheet's side bar and filter the tasks as I select a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I understand that we can write and read tasks using Google Apps Script.
I was wondering if I could have the side bar open, as I click on a certain cell, containing a data. Then, the side bar would appear, showing the tasks due on that date.

This is what I'm talking about:
[image]

Comment: I my laptop world the task window covers up the sidebar

Comment: Here's a dummy sidebar try it: `function launchASideBar() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Hello World</h1>').setTitle('Blank Sidebar'));
}`

Comment: About your question of `I was wondering if I could have the side bar open, as I click on a certain cell, containing a data.`, I thought that this thread might be the answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62647068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to open the Task sidebar from the [UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html) class. As @Tanaike references, there is also no way to activate the UI from a Simple Trigger.

> They cannot access services that require authorization.

`onSelectionChange(e)` Simple Trigger pointing to `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"` scope in this case

You could make a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113), asking for that functionality to be integrated in Apps Script.

As a workaround you can activate a sidebar by creating an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), and using [Task API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tasks) to filling it, but in that case you would only have the `edit` and `change` events available.  The trigger would only change when a value or the spreadsheet structure changed.

###### `Code.gs`

```js
const test = (e) => {
  // Getting all the task from a certain TaskList
  // this should be tweaked for obtain the TaskList from a
  // certain day 
  var tasks = Tasks.Tasks.list(TASKLIST_ID)
  if (!tasks.items) return
  Logger.log(tasks)
  let htmlContent = tasks
    .items
    .map(task => `<li>${task.title}-${task.note}</li>`).join(' ')
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutput(htmlContent)
      .setTitle('Custom Notes'))
}
```

###### Documentation

- [Simple Trigger Restrictrions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: You can open a sidebar from a menu. Then sidebar =[poll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628894/how-do-i-make-a-sidebar-display-values-from-cells/30634581#30634581)> server(properties)<=`onSelectionChange()`